# Whats does LIKE mean in SQL?

Tags: sql

Consider the following: `like [ae][^m-z]%`

What does it mean?

Comment: The internet has some good search tools.  Consider searching for "sql like expressions" (no quotes).  It might take you to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql.  Look at "Arguments".  That's not a classic "regular expression", but it's pretty close

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: That code isn't valid ANSI SQL. Which dbms are you using?

Answer (score 1):

The `LIKE` operator is used in a `WHERE` clause to search for a specified pattern in a column (in your case, the regex `[ae][^m-z]%`).

For example, the following statement:

```
SELECT randomCharacters FROM generated WHERE names LIKE [ae][^m-z]%
```

may return results  from the table `generated` in the column `randomCharacters` with values that match the SQL regex. (special emphasis on the SQL)

Comment: [THIS](https://regex101.com/r/gPrOIg/1/) should be self explanatory to help decipher the RegEx

Comment: It's not a classic _Regex_, it's a SQL `like` expression (the `%` means 0 or more characters of any type)

Comment: Nope, it could return `e%` or `abc` or `abcdef$$$` or even `ab%`.  But the `%` is significant in the same way that `.*` would be in a _Regex_

Comment: No quotes needed?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql

- `[ae]` means either `a` or `e`
- `[^m-z]` means any letter not in the range `m` through `z`
- `%` means any number of characters

Together is says "something that starts with either `a` or `e`, has a second character that is not a letter in the range `m` through `z` and is followed by anything (including nothing at all)

Here's proof:

```
declare @myTable table (StringColumn varchar(50))
insert into @myTable (StringColumn) Values 
    ('e%'), ('abc'), ('abcdef$$$'), ('ab%'), ('ab'), ('AA'),   --these ones match
    ('ba%'), ('an%'), ('GG')                                   --these ones don't
    
select * from @myTable where StringColumn  like '[ae][^m-z]%'
```

The results look like:

```
-------------------
| StringColumn    |
-------------------
| e%              |
| abc             |
| abcdef$$$       |
| ab%             |
| ab              |
| AA              |
-------------------
```

The new table formatting just doesn't seem to like me